# Epson 7620 printers require constant cleaning - why?

Tags: printing, printer, epson-workforce

I manage 4x Epson wf7620 and 1x Epson wf3620 inkjet printers.

They all use the same ink cartridges, we use non OEM cartridges through amazon, we always buy the non OEM cartridges from a reputable brand with good reviews.

The print volume on these machines is pretty low, c. 2500 prints per machine per year.

When the print heads are clean the printers work fine, but after a while the print heads get dirty and require cleaning, cleaning isnt a one off task, but instead requires 5-10 cleans back to back to get them working again.

Any reason why this would be and is there anything that can be done to prevent it ? Or is this just how inkjet printers are ?

Comment: It's how inkjets work. With some printers, less than 50% of the ink gets to the paper; the rest is wasted in cleaning cycles, either printer initiated (at every startup) or started by the users to unclog the jets. On top of that, printer ink is the most expensive liquid you can buy.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you are confusing "dirty" with being clogged. The process of cleaning a print head forces ink through the nozzles in order to clear them. My experience in tech support over the past 20 years or so has been that printers that have only occasional use will have clogged nozzles. Epson printers have been a bane in this respect, especially as many do not have replaceable heads or are very expensive to replace.

A solution is more frequent use, if only to print a test page on a periodic basis. The test page should be selected to use all colors.

Comment: True, Epsons are more prone to this problem precisely because, unlike pretty much all the others, they don't have the heads in the cartidges.

Comment: Thanks, we do tend to use the 7620's daily and the 3620's a few times a week each time with a few sheets, so they shouldnt be clogging i dont think. Is non OEM ink more prone to clogging ?

Comment: I think your usage eliminates the problem of drying in the nozzles. Non OEM ink has also been problematic in my experience.